# updating UILabel programmatically

Tags: iphone, loops, uilabel

I am trying to updating UILabel text in a loop in every iteration but it is displaying only the last value whether there is time taken for completing the loop is about 30 -50 sec.

Here is the code:

```
for (float i=0; i< [topicNew count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *new= [topicNew objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *imageName = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@.png", appDelegate.subject,topicNamed,[new objectForKey:kWordTitleKey]] autorelease];
    NSString *imagePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    NSData *imageData = [self ParsingImagePath:[new objectForKey:kWordImagePathKey]];
    [progressView setProgress:i/[topicNew count]];
    [self setProgress:i/[topicNew count]]; 
    [self.lbltest setText:@"Image Downloading..."];
    self.lbltest.text =imageName;
    //NSLog(@"sending %f",i/[topicNew count]);
    //lblpercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    [lblpercent setText:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f",i/[topicNew count]] stringByAppendingString:@"%"]];
    //[self.view addSubview:viewalert];
    [self updateLabel:self];
    NSLog(@"%@,%d",imageName,i);
    if(imageData != nil)
        [imageData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
    else
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:NULL];

    NSMutableDictionary *newWord = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[new objectForKey:kWordTitleKey], kWordTitleKey, [new objectForKey:kWordDefinitionKey], kWordDefinitionKey, imagePath, kWordImagePathKey, appDelegate.subject,kSubjectKey,topicName,kTopicKey,[new objectForKey:kWordMemorizedKey], kWordMemorizedKey, nil];
    [newTopic addObject:newWord];

}
```

Comment: It is quite impossible to answer a question ... without a question.

Comment: By the way, where did you define the UILabel attribute? Are you generating it programmatically or through Interface Builder?

Comment: Have to agree on marzapower here. Seems to me you have two problems: you can only get the last value on your label instead of all... and your loop takes way too long to complete. Please define your questions properly so helpful people don't have to ask questions about your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your thread is lock by your loop. So you need to perform your method in background and use

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil];
```

Don't forget to put in "myMethod";

```
-(void)myMethod{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
//I do my label update
[pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are using it now, replaces the text indeed. I don't know which label you'd like to update. If you want to update, for example, `lbltest` with what's being downloaded all the time, you should change `self.lbltest.text = imageName;` to `[self.lbltest setText:@"%@ %@", self.lbltest.text, imageName];`

That way, your old text doesn't get replaced by your new text, but your new text gets added to your old text.

Using `labelName.text = @"Something";` changes the text on that label to `Something`.

The same goes for `[labelName setText:@"Something"];`.

Whenever you use any of the two described above, you'll replace the text in that label with the text "Something". If you want to add something to that label, you have to include the old text in your new String.